# Always move cursor to top of gitcommit buffer

Tags: autocmd, git

I have the following `autocmd` in my vimrc.

```
augroup line_return
  au!
  au BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \     execute 'normal! g`"zvzz' |
    \ endif
augroup END
```

It moves the cursor to the line it was on when the file was previously opened.

I like this behaviour generally, but I don't want this behaviour when writing a Git commit. I tried adding the following `autocmd`, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't think the syntax is wrong since I see no errors when starting Vim. I *think* it's because it runs *before* the first `autocmd` runs, but I'm not sure.

```
augroup always_start_at_top_of_git_commit
  au!
  au FileType gitcommit execute 'normal! gg'
augroup END
```

How can I make this work? Should I actually just add a conditional to the first `autocmd` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `:h last-position-jump` with a recent vim?

It has almost the same autocommand as yours but with 'commit' in mind:

```
            *restore-cursor* *last-position-jump*  >
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
  \ |   exe "normal! g`\""
  \ | endif
```

See the last condition `&ft !~# 'commit'` -- it checks the filetype of the buffer and if it has no 'commit' in it then jump to the given position.